# Python 3.6.5 - os.makedirs / os.mkdir doesn't create directory without any error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I need any help for a weird problem with my Python 3.6.5 code.
*The error is only produced during my project execution, I haven't succeeded to recreate it during another script execution...*
I would like to create some folders during `__init__` function into some class, with os.makedirs :

```
self.working_folder = Preprocessor.prepare_folder(working_folder)  # create final working folder
self.previews_folder = Preprocessor.prepare_folder(previews_folder)  # create previews folder
```

Here the "working_folder" is created instead "previews_folder" isn't, **without any error.**
If I try this code :

```
self.working_folder = Preprocessor.prepare_folder(working_folder)  # create final working folder
Preprocessor.prepare_folder(previews_folder)  # create previews folder
```

Both folders are created correctly.

Details about "Preprocessor.prepare_folder" :

```
    def prepare_folder(folder_path):
    print("Path to create: ", folder_path)
    while True:
        try:
            os.makedirs(folder_path)
            print("Folder created as: ", folder_path)
            return folder_path
        except FileExistsError:
            if folder_path[-1] in ("/", "\\"):
                folder_path = folder_path[:len(folder_path) - 1]
            if folder_path[-1].isdigit():
                temp = folder_path[-1]
                for i in range(len(folder_path) - 2, -1, -1):
                    try:
                        if folder_path[i].isdigit():
                            temp = folder_path[i] + temp
                        else:
                            folder_path = folder_path[:i + 1]
                            break
                    except IndexError:
                        raise EnvironmentError
                folder_path = folder_path + str(int(temp) + 1)
            else:
                folder_path += '1'
```

Operating System : Windows 10 x64 Family

**Tracebacks:**

```
Path to create:  C:\Users\MPuis\Downloads\Tests\classifier_temp
Folder created as:  C:\Users\MPuis\Downloads\Tests\classifier_temp
Path to create:  C:\Users\MPuis\Downloads\Tests\previews_temp
Folder created as:  C:\Users\MPuis\Downloads\Tests\previews_temp

Process finished with exit code 0
```

DOS terminal with "dir" command:

```
Répertoire de C:\Users\MPuis\Downloads\Tests

11/04/2018  23:42    <DIR>          .
11/04/2018  23:42    <DIR>          ..
11/04/2018  23:42    <DIR>          classifier_temp
10/04/2018  12:18    <DIR>          Models
10/04/2018  13:12    <DIR>          To_sort
               0 fichier(s)                0 octets
               5 Rép(s)  113 340 448 768 octets libres
```

**Minimal class sample (creates correctly both folders, unsucceeded to recreate issue, however those are the same class, values and concerned functions than the other which doesn't work)**

```
""" A script sample of error """

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os

    output_folder = os.path.abspath("C:/Users/MPuis/Downloads/Tests/Models")


    class Preprocessor:
        # ---- Settings ----
        default_wfolder = 'classifier_temp'
        default_previews = 'previews_temp'

        def __init__(self, target_folder, working_folder=default_wfolder, previews_folder=default_previews):
            if working_folder == Preprocessor.default_wfolder:
                working_folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(target_folder)), working_folder)
            if previews_folder == Preprocessor.default_previews:
                previews_folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(target_folder)), previews_folder)
            self.target_folder = target_folder
            self.working_folder = Preprocessor.prepare_folder(working_folder)  # create final working folder

            # Error with this statement
            self.previews_folder = Preprocessor.prepare_folder(previews_folder)  # create previews folder

        @staticmethod
        def prepare_folder(folder_path):
            print("Path to create: ", folder_path)
            while True:
                try:
                    os.makedirs(folder_path)
                    print("Folder created as: ", folder_path)
                    return folder_path
                except FileExistsError:
                    print("File exists")
                    return None


    test = Preprocessor(target_folder=output_folder)
    print("Script done")
```

Have you any suggestions about that weird issue ?
Thank you for any help !

**EDIT**
After some tests I tried this code:

```
self.working_folder = Preprocessor.prepare_folder(working_folder)  # create final working folder
self.previews_folder = Preprocessor.prepare_folder(previews_folder)  # create previews folder
os.makedirs(self.previews_folder)
```

and then I caught an error: "FileExistsError: [WinError 183]", however a "dir" command into DOS terminal wrote same result than precedent tests...

Comment: Please post the complete error message including traceback.

Comment: I'm sorry but the issue is that: there isn't any error or traceback.

Comment: Do you have logging that shows which paths through `prepare_folder` are actually taken? Do you have any `..` elements on the path?

Comment: Sure, I added it into the post

Comment: Can you include a minimal example of the class with just the methods/statements needed to reproduce the problem and the values you are passing for the folder_paths?  [mcve]

Comment: Your output doesn't match the code that supposedly produced it; the print calls in the code you've shown us don't print in that format. Voting to close for no MCVE.

Comment: I am updating the post as accurately as possible according to the details requested

Comment: You need to carefully compare the working example you posted here and your *production* code to see what the differences are and start testing to see if those differences are the problem.

Comment: Thank you wwii for your answer, I've read again and again all my production code as you advised, exposing the issue helped me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved after compare Class sample and Production Class**
(as suggested by wwii)
In my class Preprocessor, it was the `__del__` function which remove the "previews_folder" before exit, obviously.

Thank you all for your help